# ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters in ApexComponent and in Visualpage are different?

Tags: visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I am trying to pass url parameters between Apexpages and component but am not successful in achieving this. When I call **ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters().put('test','aaa')**

in a pagecontroller and then call **ApexPage.currentPage.getParameters().get('test')** in a component controller which resides in that page. The method returns nothing. Can someone tell me how can I persist the url parameters between page controller and component controller?

thank you

Comment: maybe my question was not clear. I have a page with pagecontroller and in this page there is a component with component controller.  what I am trying to do is call Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put in pagecontroller and call Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get in componentcontroller. I tried this and get nothing returned. should this not share the same link url and parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question was unclear. You said that the value needs to be pass from the page to controller.but if the value is dynamic then you have to workaround on `<apex:param>` tag.

If you are passing the parameters like **ID** then You have to append the URL of vf page with your ID and value like below

https://yourdomainname/apex/vfpagename?**test=value**

And get the parameter in the controller using

`ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters().get('test');`

**Update:**

Try the below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096wsIAA

Hope this might helps....

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am not passing parameter from page to page controller, I am trying to read page paramters in a component controller.  the component is in that page and I think It share the same link with the page.

Comment: Try like in my updated link

Comment: thank for the link, unfortunately I can't add new attribute to our existing component, there is a button on component it just redirect to the current page and refresh the current page, then all my page parameters is gone. what I can change is the return behavior, I have solved this by add cookie, put all my parameters in cookie and then if the component  cancell button is clicked, then I set another cookie. which the page loading again, i have the url parameter cookie and the cookie set by cancel button, then I can read the parameters again and delete the cookie set by compoent cancel button.

Comment: @Subhash your link is broken, can you please update it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();

pageRef.getParameters().put('test', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('test'));

pageRef.setRedirect(true);

return pageRef;
```

Comment: yes, I did this,  I have a page and in that page there is an component.  what I am trying to do is, call apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put() in the page controller, and want to get this url parameter in component controller.

Comment: Would you mind to put your code please.